# What is the best way to retrieve soccer games by league names in redis?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I have a hundreds of soccer games saved in my redus database. They are saved in hashes under the key: `games:soccer:data` I have three z sets to clasify them into upcoming, live, and ended. All ordered by date (score). This way I can easily retrieve them depending on if will start soon, they are already happening, or they already ended. Now, i want to be able to retrieve them by league names.

I came up with two alternatives:

***First alternative:*** save single hashes containing the game id and the league name. This way I can get all live game ids and then check each id against their respective hashes, if it matches the league name(s) i want, then i push it into an array, if not, i skip it. Finally, return the array with all game ids for the leagues i wanted.

***Second alternative:*** create keys for each league and have live, upcoming, and ended sets for each. This way, i think, it would be faster to retrieve the game ids; however, it would be a pain to maintain each set.

If you have any other way of doing this, please let me know. I don't know if sorting would be faster and save me some memory.

I am looking for speed and low memory usage.

***EDIT*** (following hobbs alternative):

```
      const multi = client.multi();
      const tempSet = 'users:data:14:sports:soccer:lists:temp_' + getTimestamp();

      return multi
      .sunionstore(
        tempSet,
        [
          'sports:soccer:lists:leagueNames:Bundesliga',
          'sports:soccer:lists:leagueNames:La Liga'
        ]
      )
      .zinterstore(
        'users:data:14:sports:soccer:lists:live',
        2,
        'sports:lists:live',
        tempSet
      )
      .del(tempSet)
      .execAsync()
```

I need to set `AGGREGATE MAX` to my query and I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a SET containing all of the games for each league, and use ZINTERSTORE to compute the intersection between your league sets and your existing sets. You could do the ZINTERSTORE every time you query the data (it's not a horribly expensive operation unless your data is very large), or you could do it only when writing to one of the "parent" sets, or you could treat it as a sort of cache by giving it a short TTL and creating it only if it doesn't exist when you go to query it.

Comment: What happens if this SET containing all of the games for each league gets very big with thousands of entries? Does its size matter?

Comment: @ElPirru it does matter, but thousands is not "very big" and not likely to be a problem. But to be sure, create some test data and measure performance!

Comment: I will run some tests and post back the results. I could delete games older than x amount of time to keep the size "small" or have two SETs, one with games newer than a month and the other list with the rest of the games. What if i retirieve a game's league from its hash and then make a new set from there? This would be using the sort function i guess....

Comment: I am having a hard time implementing zinterstore with more than two keys and I can't find a way to set `AGGREGATE MAX` in node-redis. Can I have multiple sets for each league or do I need only one set for all of them? Because right now, it seems I need to do sunion first on the league sets and then apply a zinterstore. Could you please provide an example setting `AGGREGATE MAX` in node redis please? I tried looking it up on google but did not find any examples.